# What happens if I run Geth --rpc a second time

Tags: go-ethereum

I was running Geth --rpc overnight but I think that my computer has restarted following a Windows update.

without thinking I just ran again Geth --rpc a second time, but I am not sure that was the right thing to do. maybe I should have cancelled the action of the first run of Geth.

Does anybody know what happens when you run Geth --rpc twice?

thanks for teaching me!
Hsoda

Answer (score 0):

By default there are several resources that a geth instance will try to access exclusively. Like the blockchain data directory, the p2p port 30303, or the rpc port 8545.

If some of this resources are already used by a previous instance. The new instance of geth will refuse to start with a message indicating the failure.